# RegEx match between two words and get all occurrences

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am cleaning up XML files that contain HTML by using RegEx.

Some files contain multiple `style`-elements and I want to remove them all and content in between. For example:

[(Test here on regex101...)](https://regex101.com/r/OHHkQ8/2)

```
&lt;STYLE&gt;
   group 1
&lt;/STYLE&gt;
   Random text here which shall not be removed.
&lt;STYLE&gt;
   group 2
&lt;/STYLE&gt;
   Some more random text here which shall not be removed.
&lt;STYLE&gt;
   group 3
&lt;/STYLE&gt;
```

I am using the following RegEx with /s parameter

```cs
(&lt;STYLE&gt;).*(&lt;\/STYLE&gt;)
```

Problem is that this RegEx will match everything between `<style>` (`#1`) and last `</style>` (`#3`).

I would like to match only `group`, `<style>`, and `</style>` elements. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You have accepted a solution, but do realise that will only remove the first style and group, ie. you can't use it to set the second (in its current form)

Comment: @grail - the accepted solution actually does the work correctly when using /sg flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making the regex non greedy by using the `?` operator:

```
(&lt;STYLE&gt;).*?(&lt;\/STYLE&gt;)
                ^^^ use ? to tell the regex engine to stop at the first closing tag
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: So simple! Thanks :)